# Ionic 2 (click) fires twice iOS 10.3.1

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I`m developing an app on ionic 2, but i have an issue with click event.

When I run the app on the device and try to click on a button for example to make an alert, this function fires once, but when I click again the button, the function fires twice.

This is the system information.

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.2.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

And this is the example code:

home.htm

```
<div padding>
    <button ion-button full (click)="TestAlert()">Alert</button>
</div>
```

home.ts

```
TestAlert(){

     console.log('Hola');
     alert('Hola');
  }
```

This is a full example what i`m doing [repo](https://github.com/jorgemejia/PersonalProject2)

Comment: thats because the btn has a click listener by default and you add a second one. try to make the click call in js not in html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `(tap)` instead of `(click)`.

(since you're using ionic-native 3.0.1 there's a change that tap will interfere with the scroll, if this happens you'll need to update to 3.1.1).

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks this works. In case of my iOS app function is called twice. Ex: if I call a function this.make_shortlisted() from ionViewDidLoad() it will be called twice, which is creating delay of page load for me.

Answer (score -3):

HTML

```
<div padding>
    <button type="button" class="ion-button full">Alert</button> 
</div>
```

JS

```
// wait until all dom elements are loaded
$(document).ready(function(){

  // init TestAlert as Listener 
  var TestAlert = function(){
    console.log('Hola');
    alert('Hola');
  }

  // bind the click event to the button
  $('button').on('click', TestAlert);
});
```

Comment: The problem here is the ionic framework is based on angular2 and i`m not using jquery I use typescript.

Comment: you can rewrite my code with vanilla js, i just was to lazy for this and used jquery because it's faster.

Comment: jquery is faster ,hahaha ,,

Comment: it's faster to write jquery than vanilla